# Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, github, dependencies

I added this library from GitHub into my android app:

```
implementation 'com.github.quiin:unifiedContactPicker:1.0'
```

Now, this library uses other libraries from GitHub.
When I run my app, it tells me that these internal libraries are not found, so I dig them up and find their dependencies and add them to my app's Gradle file. But the problem is that they are not being detected and this is the error I am getting both times.

Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.hootsuite.android:nachos:1.0.0.
> Required by:
> project :app > com.github.quiin:unifiedContactPicker:1.0

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Please help, I have been stuck at this for a long time and I need to use this dependency. I have also tried using similar dependencies that fulfil my purpose but they all seem to have the same problem. So I don't know if there's a problem with my project or the libraries.

Comment: same problem any solution?

Comment: No, I just built my own Contact Picker

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with [geok](https://github.com/piruin/geok) library. I checked syntax of dependencies declaration lines on [JitPack](https://jitpack.io/) website and there were different than I had on my build.gradle file. Finally I changed

from:

```
implementation "com.github.piruin:geok:$geokVersion"
implementation "com.github.piruin.geok-gson:$geokVersion"
```

to:

```
implementation "com.github.piruin.geok:geok:$geokVersion"
implementation "com.github.piruin.geok:geok:$geokVersion"
```

and it works.